# jQuery slide fade content

Tags: java, jquery, css, ajax

I have found this code to put it in one of the pages. But I couldn't figure out how to make one of them active as soon as going in the website. Direct link to first item does now work. How can we make the first link active as soon as we get in the website?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>
        <title>Demo: jQuery Slide &amp; Fade Content</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slide-fade-content.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.more').live('click',function(){
                    var href = $(this).attr('href');
                    if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
                        $('#ajax').css('display','block').animate({height:'1px'}).empty();
                    }
                    $('#ajax').css('display','block').animate({height:'200px'},function(){
                        $('#ajax').html('<img class="loader" src="loader.gif" alt="">');
                        $('#ajax').load('slide-fade-content.html #'+href,function(){
                            $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn().highlightFade({color:'rgb(253,253,175)'});
                        });
                    });
                    return true;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="demo">
                <table width="900" border="1"><tr><td width="150" valign="top"><ul>
                    <li><a class="more" href="#first-item">First Item</a></li>
                    <li><a class="more" href="#second-item">Second Item</a></li>
                    <li><a class="more" href="#third-item">Third Item</a></li>
                </ul></td>
                <td width="750"><div id="ajax"></div></td></tr></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One of "them?"  One of what?

Comment: one of the links within the <table>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I usually accomplish this is to trigger the event manually on load, as seen below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>
        <title>Demo: jQuery Slide &amp; Fade Content</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slide-fade-content.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.more').live('click',function(){
                    var href = $(this).attr('href');
                    if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
                        $('#ajax').css('display','block').animate({height:'1px'}).empty();
                    }
                    $('#ajax').css('display','block').animate({height:'200px'},function(){
                        $('#ajax').html('<img class="loader" src="loader.gif" alt="">');
                        $('#ajax').load('slide-fade-content.html #'+href,function(){
                            $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn().highlightFade({color:'rgb(253,253,175)'});
                        });
                    });
                    return true;
                });

             $('.more').first().click();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="demo">
                <table width="900" border="1"><tr><td width="150" valign="top"><ul>
                    <li><a class="more" href="#first-item">First Item</a></li>
                    <li><a class="more" href="#second-item">Second Item</a></li>
                    <li><a class="more" href="#third-item">Third Item</a></li>
                </ul></td>
                <td width="750"><div id="ajax"></div></td></tr></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The one addition is `$('.more').first().click();` added after the click event is bound.  Then I take the first `more` link and `click` it. See it live here http://jsfiddle.net/eEk2v/

Comment: +1 for a working solution - I'd take this and refine it further by breaking the "click" code out into a function, then calling the function in doc.ready. Apart from being semantically incorrect, manually triggering a click just feels odd!

Comment: Semantically incorrect?  Explain.  I could have written it in jquery longform as `$('.more').first().trigger('click')` and this is a perfectly acceptable way of triggering a jQuery event handler as well.  Both methods are basically the same form of triggering a jquery event handler, and it is pretty commonly used.  So I'm not sure what you don't like about it.

Comment: Thank You Eli it works very nice and also thanks for the explanation

Comment: I mean incorrect in the sense that when you read the code, instead of seeing the flow `doc.ready` -> `attach click handler` -> `define function` -> `execute function against first link` we read `doc.ready` -> `attach click handler` -> `click first link`, but hey we're just arguing semantics - your solution still stands =)

Comment: ok sounds good.  I don't protest to know it all, so I wanted to make sure there wasn't some fundamental semantic or syntactic rule I was violating.  To me it's more of an argument of style and how you the code. When it comes to jquery event triggering, I actually read it more similar to the first execution path because I see it as executing a method (or multiple methods!) of an event-driven system.  Anyway, appreciate the feedback.  Cheers